# Is asking about making specific dice in specific dice-rolling utilities on topic?

Tags: support, questions, on-topic

For instance, let's say I want to ask the question "I want to make an Anima: Beyond Fantasy die in the Rolisteam dice roller, how do I do that?".  (As it happens, I *do* want to ask this question, since making an Anima: Beyond Fantasy die is nontrivial (explosions, for one, require specific behavior that I could not immediately figure out how to implement).)  Is asking this question on-topic for this site?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Yes, questions about using RPG tools to simulate dice rolls for existing RPGs is certainly on-topic.

Questions about dice as they relate to RPGs are generally on-topic, as long as they're not some sort of open-ended request for help designing a game. Questions about RPG tools, as long as they are clear and properly scoped, are also welcome on RPG.SE. So narrowing this down, asking about using a specific RPG tool to simulate dice used in a specific RPG is definitely fine.

In particular, your example for using a dice roller tool to simulate a particular sort of die roll used in *Anima: Beyond Fantasy* seems very much on-topic.

Comment: Asked!  https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/147229/i-would-like-to-simulate-a-die-from-anima-beyond-fantasy-in-the-rolisteam-dice#147229